# Scala - Dequeue doesn't return correct result

Tags: scala, queue

I have a queue of List[Any], but somehow dequeue doesn't return correct result and it doesn't remove the item from the queue either. Any idea why this happened?

Here is an example:

```
scala> val a = scala.collection.immutable.Queue(List(1, "A", "B", 987), List(2, "C", "D", 456), List(3, "E", "F", 123))
a: scala.collection.immutable.Queue[List[Any]] = Queue(List(1, A, B, 987), List(2, C, D, 456), List(3, E, F, 123))

scala> a.dequeue
res5: (List[Any], scala.collection.immutable.Queue[List[Any]]) = (List(1, A, B, 987),Queue(List(2, C, D, 456), List(3, E, F, 123)))

scala> a
res6: scala.collection.immutable.Queue[List[Any]] = Queue(List(1, A, B, 987), List(2, C, D, 456), List(3, E, F, 123))
```

Comment: `val (elem, newQ) = oldQ.dequeue`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You used an immutable queue, so `dequeue` does not modify the original queue but rather returns a modified one together with the head element as tuple:

```
val (elem, newQ) = oldQ.dequeue
```

For example, you can feed the tail queue into a recursive call for processing. Something like this:

```
def pq(q: Queue[List[Any]]): Unit = {
  q.dequeue match {
    case (head, tail) => 
      println(head + "..."); // ... process head element ...
      if (tail.nonEmpty) pq(tail)
  }
}
```

Comment: then what is the purpose of immutable queue if one couldn't dequeue from it? I heard in Scala it is a good practice to use an immutable type.

Comment: can you give an example in your answer?

Comment: I've updated my answer , hope this gives an idea. Of course it depends on your use-case, sometimes a mutable collection is a better fit.

Comment: fixed typo & added example to just get tuple result (thanks, @jwvh )